# Is a random variate a functional?

Tags: statistics

A https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variate is a particular outcome of a random variable. I was wondering what is meant in the Wikipedia article with "a random variate is corresponding to a probability distribution". Does this mean a random variate is in principle a functional $\Phi[f(x)]$ with $f(x)$ being some probability distribution?

Comment: I think the expected value of a distribution certainly would be